# Impact on wall integrity when installing outlets on baseboards vs. higher up on lath-and-plaster wall?

Tags: electrical, lath-and-plaster

I'm getting new outlets installed in a second floor room and am trying to decide whether to install them in the baseboard or higher up on the wall. I have:

- Lath-and-plaster walls
- No crawlspace and at most a small amount of "attic" space that isn't easily accessible (and certainly cannot fit a person)

The last time I had outlets added to a different room, the contractor added the outlets to the baseboard, as he claimed it reduces the chances of plaster cracking more broadly and is better for the wall's structural integrity. I've seen similar reasons mentioned online in random forums.

I don't quite understand why this makes sense:

1. When you install an outlet in the baseboard, you still have to cut away at plaster behind the baseboard to fit the electrical box.
2. Removing baseboard from a lath-and-plaster wall results in quite a bit of plaster breaking off in that area.
3. In my particular case, the lack of crawlspace and hard-to-access attic resulted in the last contractor routing the cabling behind the baseboards, notching the studs, and adding metal plates in those places. This required removing quite a bit of the wall at the base.

My question is, in my case, **is it better/worse for my wall's structural integrity if I install outlets in the baseboard vs. higher up on the wall? Should I route my next set of outlets through the baseboard or ask the contractor to route the cabling into the hard-to-use attic space to prevent damage to my wall?**

I'm aware it's easier to hide the work behind baseboards. I also know that some people find it more aesthetically pleasing to have the outlets in the baseboard. I'm also guessing it's much easier to route the cabling behind the baseboard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having outlets so low on the wall that they're in the baseboard strikes me as _very_ unusual. In fact, yours may be one of the few legitimate use cases for it. I would be very wary of notching studs to run wiring, however, as that can compromise the integrity of the stud and there are rules about how much notching is allowed and where the notches can be. (I don't know them off-hand, but I'm sure someone will be able to quote them for you.)

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for the reply - I think it's reasonably common in older houses. I ended up installing the outlets higher up though in this particular case, and I definitely learned more about some of the issues of cutting plaster higher up.